# Whats the proper way for scaling text?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, user-experience

I am developing a Qt QML based application that runs on both Desktop and Mobile operating systems. I am having problems with proper fonts and components scaling- what does look good on large, desktop monitor is barely visible on a mobile phone, even though the scaling is the same.

I was wondering, what is the proper approach for this problem? I would like to run the same code on all platforms. For example, is there a way for a font to stay the same size (in mm or inches), no matter the screen resolution and size?

In QML I am always setting the `font.pointSize` property. It is scaled evenly, but because of that, the font are barely visible on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `font.pixelSize` property yet?
I think this will be good for you.

"Sets the font size in pixels.

Using this function makes the font device dependent. Use pointSize to set the size of the font in a device independent manner."

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#font.pixelSize-prop